# Nodejs create simple queue on Async

Tags: javascript, node.js

in this below sample code i can run multi function on the same time

```
Promise.all([sendMoneyToRequestedUser(_data), saveTransferMoneyTransaction(_data)])
    .then(function (results) {
        log.info("OOOOOOOOOOOOOo");
    }).catch(function (error) {
    log.info(error)
});
```

but i want to create simple queue for them, for example, can i implementing that with `Promise` with this solution? I have 3 functions `check`, `send`, and `post`, that I want to run in series and pass the result of each step to the other.

**Step 1**, `check()` function, **Step 2**, `send()` function and then after finish them execute function for example `post()`

for this implementation i need to get result of each steps, for example get result from **Step 1**, if its return true then on **Step 2** i need to use result of **Step 1**,

is `async.parallel` solution for this implementation? or `Promise` can doing that

Comment: What are `check`, `send`, and `post` functions?

Comment: @YanFoto they are working with database with mySql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The question is not really clear on what is given, and what is desired. From the comments, I've got the following:

three functions of `check`, `send`, and `post` are given and it is desired to be run in series.

Let's say that the mentioned `check`, `send`, and `post` all return Promises, e.g.:

```js
function check() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // Do some stuff and save them in a var 'results'
    var results = ...;
    resolve(results);
  });
}
```

Then you can simply build a queue as follows:

```js
check()
  .then(send)
  .then(post)
  .catch(function(err) { console.error(err); })
```

At each level the function is called with the value resolved from the previous level.

Comment: in your code, `send` can get result from `check` or `post` can get result from `send` ist right?

Comment: Exactly. They each should return a promise and the result that they want to pass on, should be passed by calling the Promise's `resolve` function.

Comment: then what are `([sendMoneyToRequestedUser(_data), saveTransferMoneyTransaction(_data)]` functions? could you write simple function as `check`? this functions have `function()` argument?

Comment: I don't know, you tell me what they are :D. I cannot give you any details, as your question doesn't provide enough details.

Comment: oh! i'm sorry, you suppose i dont have `sendMoneyToRequestedUser(_data)` and `saveTransferMoneyTransaction(_data)` functions

Comment: I operated on the information you provided. I don't know which functions are available and which are not.

Comment: you suppose i have only `check`,`send` and `post` functions, not more than that, chaining three function as  `check`,`send` and `post`

Comment: The concept stays the same. You start your first promise and chain the rest of promises using `then`. See the updated answer

Comment: @tux-world glad I could help :)

Answer (score 10):

**Update:**

There's a module for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-queue

**Old answer:**

I was having issues while trying to use all kinds of modules, and finally I wrote the simplest implementation I could think of for this kind of work.

Check out this simple class I wrote (Plain JS):

```
class Queue {
    constructor(maxSimultaneously = 1) {
        this.maxSimultaneously = maxSimultaneously;
        this.__active = 0;
        this.__queue = [];
    }
    
    /** @param { () => Promise<T> } func 
     * @template T
     * @returns {Promise<T>}
    */
    async enqueue(func) {
        if(++this.__active > this.maxSimultaneously) {
            await new Promise(resolve => this.__queue.push(resolve));
        }

        try {
            return await func();
        } catch(err) {
            throw err;
        } finally {
            this.__active--;
            if(this.__queue.length) {
                this.__queue.shift()();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

Lets say you have this async function:

```
const printNumber = async (n) => {
    await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 2000)); // wait 2 sec
    console.log(n);
}
```

so, instead of:

```
await printNumber(1);
await printNumber(2);
await printNumber(3);
await printNumber(4);
```

use:

```
const q = new Queue();

q.enqueue(() => printNumber(1));
q.enqueue(() => printNumber(2));
q.enqueue(() => printNumber(3));
q.enqueue(() => printNumber(4));
```

Each function will be executed once the others are done.

The output:

```
1 // after 2 sec
2 // after 4 sec
3 // after 6 sec
4 // after 8 sec
```

Or you can limit the queue to run up to some number of functions at the same time:

```
const q = new Queue(3);

q.enqueue(() => printNumber(1));
q.enqueue(() => printNumber(2));
q.enqueue(() => printNumber(3));
q.enqueue(() => printNumber(4));
```

The output:

```
1 // after 2 sec
2 // after 2 sec
3 // after 2 sec
4 // after 4 sec
```

**Also**, the enqueue method will return/throw the original data from your promise!

Lets suppose you write an API to upload files, and you want to limit the uploads to up to 5 at the same time. You want everything to stay the same as it was, without changing your flow. Here's how you can do that:

```
async function upload(data) {
    // upload...
    if(something) {
        return 200;
    } else {
        throw 400;
    }
}
```

So, instead of doing this:

```
async function work(data) { 
    // do something...
    return await upload(data);
}
```

do this:

```
const q = new Queue(5); // up to 5 at the same time
async function work(data) { 
    // do something...
    return await q.enqueue(() => upload(data));
}
```

```js
class Queue {
    constructor(maxSimultaneously = 1) {
        this.maxSimultaneously = maxSimultaneously;
        this.__active = 0;
        this.__queue = [];
    }

    /** @param { () => Promise<T> } func 
     * @template T
     * @returns {Promise<T>}
    */
    async enqueue(func) {
        if(++this.__active > this.maxSimultaneously) {
            await new Promise(resolve => this.__queue.push(resolve));
        }

        try {
            return await func();
        } catch(err) {
            throw err;
        } finally {
            this.__active--;
            if(this.__queue.length) {
                this.__queue.shift()();
            }
        }
    }
}

const printNumber = async (n) => {
    await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 2000)); // wait 2 sec
    console.log(n);
}

async function start() {
    console.log('starting...');
    const q = new Queue();
    
    q.enqueue(() => printNumber(1));
    q.enqueue(() => printNumber(2));
    q.enqueue(() => printNumber(3));
    q.enqueue(() => printNumber(4));
}
```

```html
Click this to run 1 log per 2 sec: <button onclick="start();">Start</button>
```

```js
class Queue {
    constructor(maxSimultaneously = 1) {
        this.maxSimultaneously = maxSimultaneously;
        this.__active = 0;
        this.__queue = [];
    }

    /** @param { () => Promise<T> } func 
     * @template T
     * @returns {Promise<T>}
    */
    async enqueue(func) {
        if(++this.__active > this.maxSimultaneously) {
            await new Promise(resolve => this.__queue.push(resolve));
        }

        try {
            return await func();
        } catch(err) {
            throw err;
        } finally {
            this.__active--;
            if(this.__queue.length) {
                this.__queue.shift()();
            }
        }
    }
}

const printNumber = async (n) => {
    await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 2000)); // wait 2 sec
    console.log(n);
}

async function start() {
    console.log('starting...');
    const q = new Queue(3);
    
    q.enqueue(() => printNumber(1));
    q.enqueue(() => printNumber(2));
    q.enqueue(() => printNumber(3));
    q.enqueue(() => printNumber(4));
}
```

```html
Click this to run up to 3 logs every 2 sec: <button onclick="start();">Start</button>
```

Comment: you made my day ☀️

Answer (score 3):

I think that you're looking for this [`async.series`](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#series). Is runs an array of functions one after another in sequential order and passes an array of results to the callbacks from the previous functions.

**Example**

```
var async = require('async');

async.series([
    function(callback) {
        //Do a bunch of relevant stuff
        callback(null, 'First function');
    },
    function(callback) {
        //Do some more relevant stuff
        callback(null, 'Second function');
    }
],
function(err, results) {
    console.log(results); //Logs ['First function', 'Second function']
});
```

Comment: could you take an simple example on your post for me?